# How to reference the last digits of a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select rows from a table only if the last digit of a particular column value is not zero.

```
SELECT *  
FROM #table  
WHERE RIGHT(column, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9
```

is not returning the correct values. I think it's because the data is stored as a string in scientific notation. Please help!
UPDATE: fixed it! it turned out to be a problem with the data type

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What type of field is column?  char or varchar?

Comment: `RIGHT(trim(column), 1) ='0'`?  pretty sure right is SQL server as is #table and if it's char data then it's padded to be same size... thus perhaps a trim is called for.

Comment: it's sql-server and I'm not sure whether it's varchar or char or how to find out

Comment: If you have access to management studio you can just check the table / column properties. Also sp_help will return column info and does not require management studio.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) operator if the column is an `int`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #table
WHERE column % 10 <> 0
```

if the data contains numbers in scientific notation, you can use the [str()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM #table
WHERE right(str(column),1) <> 0
```

this will convert the value of the column to a number stored in a varchar.  If you have a value of `3e2`, this will become `300`.  If you have a value of `1.234e2`, this will be rounded to `123`.  See [str()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) for information about handling non-integers.

Comment: oh it turned out not to be an int

Comment: Please see answer for possible method to handle scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild Card Operator i.e. LIKE

```
Select * from Your Table where COlumn Name Like '%0';
```

For more details you can visit on the given links

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM #table
WHERE SUBSTRING(REVERSE(column), 1, 1) = '0'
```

Comment: somehow that didn't return any results

Comment: Try SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RTRIM(column)), 1, 1) = '0'

Answer (score 0):

What's in the data?
If the column has trailing space then you would not get rows.  The second select statement; with rtirm(c1) removes the spaces.  Updated the answer to match the updated question.

```
declare @test table (
 c1 varchar(10)
)

insert into @test (c1) values ('row 0');
insert into @test (c1) values ('row 0 ');
insert into @test (c1) values ('row 1');
insert into @test (c1) values ('row 1 ');
insert into @test (c1) values ('row 2');
insert into @test (c1) values ('row 2 ');

select * from @test where right(c1, 1) != '0'
select * from @test where right(rtrim(c1), 1) != '0'
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it has spacing-- could I use rtrim without risking cutting off something important?

Comment: Yes. rtrim only removes spaces (ascii 32).